# Can ARIMA Models be used to models stock prices?

Tags: arima, model, finance, acf-pacf

I'm learning about ARIMA models and other variants (SARIMAX, ARIMAX...etc)
The problem is that whenever I try fitting the closing prices for a given stock (Google, Amazon or Netflix for example), the Auto ARIMA model predict that a SARIMAX(0,1,0) is the best fit which always give me a linear line for predictions, while the actual data is highly volatile and somehow seasonal.

[image]

Even If I use an ARIMA model setting the p, d, q parameters by hand I get an even worse prediction (sometimes all prediction are close to zero while closing prices (actual values) are in the range of 1000).

Here's the PACF and ACF for the first differences (closing_price(ti) - closing_price(t(i-1) )

[image]

[image]

Most coefficient looks non stationary, so I don't know if an ARIMA model is a good model to forecast stock prices (I had this issue with several stocks: Google, Apple, Netflix...etc)

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or is the model by nature not adapted for this kind of time series ?

Comment: Hi: Don't try to forecast stock prices. Try to forecast returns. Even that is not easy but you might get parameters back that are more interesting. For example, arima(0,1,1) is sometimes useful for short term returns. prices are extremely non-stationary so not good to try to predict.

Comment: @mlofton, forecasting prices and returns are equivalent. Given today's price, predicting tomorrow price is equivalent to predicting tomorrow's return. Give me one, I will tell you the other. Also, do short-term returns tend to have a unit root? How short is short?

Comment: @Richard Hardy: No , that's not correct. Forecasting prices and forecasting returns is not equivalent. Yes, one can be obtained from the other but the prediction process-model should use returns. This is because prices are extremely non-stationary. Sometimes returns can be also ( in mean not variance ) but to a much less degree. In the time-series econometrics framework, prediction using prices doesn't make sense. The variance of prices changes over time and is proportional to the magnitude of the stock price so using stock prices  doesn't meet  the criiteria of econometric practice.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: Just one more thing. When you look at stock prices, you'll find that they often "trend". This makes them significantly non-stationary in the mean also. Yes, you can de-trend but they often trend in one direction and then another, so de-trending is useless for them also. Returns will generally hover around zero for the most part ( atleast for shorter time scales ) and the variance is generally pretty constant which is what you need econometrically. In the machine learning world, what I'm saying here may not hold. I am restricting my comment to the econometric setting.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: Note that this is why differencing exists in the ARMA world. If differencing didn't matter, then we wouldn't need the d=1 in ARIMA(p.d.q). We would just use ARMA(p.q)  ( for say log prices ) and diff the forecasts afterwards.

Comment: @mlofton, thank you for your thorough explanation. Actually, I do not disagree with anything you said. I tried to get across another point, namely, that you cannot choose to forecast returns without forecasting prices at the same time (implicitly). Whether you use ARIMA(p,d,q) for prices or ARMA(p,q) for price differences, you get the same thing. Another modification of ARMA/ARIMA would yield a model for log-returns. That is all I tried to say.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: Oh. Okay. My bad for confusion. I mistakenly thought that you meant that you could forecast returns or prices and always just get from one the other. Glad to help and sorry for confusion. Also, short term returns don't have a unit root but they can be ( or seem to be ) close to a random noise so difficult to predict.

Comment: @mlofton, then how come they could be ARIMA(0,**1**,1) (as your write above) if they do not have a unit root?

Comment: @Richard Hardy .Differencing is used when you have a non-stationary process but there doesn't necessarily have to be a unit root. But, yes, one could argue that  prices have a unit root : ( a random walk can be viewed as a unit root ) $log(p_{t}) = log(p_{t-1}) + \epsilon_t$ which is why you need to difference. Does that make sense ? Returns, on the other hand, don't have a unit root.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: Note that, when referring to the ARMA(0,1,1), I was referring to prices and not returns.

Comment: @mlofton, your formulation *For example, arima(0,1,1) is sometimes useful for short term returns* was what confused me. Now clarified. I would however be careful with differencing processes without unit roots. You get some robustness (there are works by David F. Hendry & Co showing that), but you also introduce a unit root in the error term and double its variance. The phenomenon is known as overdifferencing.

Comment: gotcha. I should have said arima(0,1,1), is sometimes useful for short term log prices. my apologies. yeah, I'm only accustomed to differencing log prices ( which is equivalent to using log returns ). But, as far as I know, differencing can be attempted even if you don't have a unit root because a unit root is just one specific form of non-stationarity.  But, yes, be aware of overdifferencing. one more hint that it may be  useful to difference is  if your acf doesn't die off at longer lags.